# Does Elasticsearch support geo queries like ST_DWithin in postgis

Tags: elasticsearch

How to perform such query in Elasticsearch that whether a geo_point is within the specified distance(or radius/buffer) of a line(depicted by 2 pairs of lat/lon)

[shape like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SF9xK.png)

Comment: one solution is to divide it into 3 queries, 2 queries of radius query of each line vertex, and a query of polygon query, but how to calculate the 4 vertices of the polygon, given the lat/lon of the 2 vertices of the line, and distance(m/km)..

Answer (score 1):

This is not implemented in Elastic as far as I know. But you can still achieve what you want by calculating the polygon offline and then use it in a [`geo_polygon`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-polygon-query.html) query. The [`geo_shape`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-shape-query.html) query could also be used but you need a `geo_shape` field instead of a `geo_point` one.

So, for instance, using [turf](https://turfjs.org/) you can precompute the polygon around the line using the `buffer` feature. Below, I'm defining a line along some road somewhere in San Jose (CA) and a buffer of 50 meters around that line/road:

```
const line = turf.lineString([[-121.862282,37.315430], [-121.851553,37.305532]], {name: 'line 1'});
const bufferPoly = turf.buffer(line, 50, {units: 'meters'});
```

You'll get the following polygon (abbreviated)

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "name": "line 1"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          -121.85121372045873,
          37.305765606399724
        ],
        [
          -121.85116304254947,
          37.30570833334188
        ],
        [
          -121.85112738572346,
          37.30564429665501
        ],
        [
          -121.85110812025259,
          37.30557595721911
        ],
        ...
        [
          -121.85121372045873,
          37.305765606399724
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Which looks like this:

[image: Polygon around line]

Then you can leverage the `geo_polygon` query like this:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "geo_polygon": {
          "your_geo_point": {
            "points": [
              [
                -121.85121372045873,
                37.305765606399724
              ],
              [
                -121.85116304254947,
                37.30570833334188
              ],
              [
                -121.85112738572346,
                37.30564429665501
              ],
              [
                -121.85110812025259,
                37.30557595721911
              ],
              ...
              [
                -121.85121372045873,
                37.305765606399724
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```